# Bazel quits before building new op without error?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I was building a new Tensorflow op with external libraries yesterday and getting errors. Today when I ran the same code for some reason I ended up with this output instead:

```
    (vent)user@server:/dir/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/user_ops$ bazel build --config opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:my_op.cc 
    INFO: Found 1 target...
    INFO: Elapsed time: 1.493s, Critical Path: 0.01s
    (vent)user@server:/dir/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/user_ops$
```

I thought it was something wrong with my cache so I did a 'bazel clean' and then tried to rebuild the example op zero_out.so, but I got the same problem even though yesterday I was able to successfully run zero_out.so from //bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops. There's nothing wrong with bazel since I was able to start building tensorflow from source without it quitting on me. My build file in //tensorflow/core/user_ops looks like this:

```
    load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

    tf_custom_op_library(
        name = "zero_out.so",
        srcs = ["zero_out.cc"],
    )

    tf_custom_op_library(
        name = "my_op.so",
        srcs = ["my_op.cc"],
        deps = ["@t//:libt"]
     )
```

I've been looking around for a couple hours, but I can't find any help and I don't think I'm looking in the right places. Does this have something to do with the bazel clean deleting some important files? None of my BUILD or WORKSPACE files were changed and nothing on my server has changed.

I'm using Bazel v0.5.1 on Linux with TF v1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the problem was simply because I had accidentally changed my_op.so to my_op.cc in the build command.